# Is the UAE sponsoring the RSF coup in Sudan?

Tags: politics, military, africa

According to a MEMO [article](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20230420-uae-behind-rsfs-attempted-coup-in-sudan-leaked-recording-says/) titled "UAE behind RSF's attempted coup in Sudan, leaked recording says":

> In the alleged audio recording, which could not be verified, a man media outlets identified as the Sudanese Army's Chief of Staff, General Kamal Abdel Marouf, said the initial change in Sudan began with a "Masonic conspiracy from within the system, and from **camel-herding countries in the Gulf that sponsored the change**, as well as foreign countries that relied on some wandering individuals in Europe who claim to be activists but are actually political traders."
>
> He added: "After announcing their change programme and the matter becoming insurmountable for them, the battle shifted to planning through the incapacitated advocates of freedom, change, the left, and the Communists. However, they reached a point where they could not achieve their ambitions, so they moved to the stage of changing by force, devising a programme and promoting it in the media, and attempting to exploit the rebel movements."
>
> He added that **Hemedti had met with UAE President Mohammed Bin Zayed and some financiers who agreed on the necessity of the change by force. This would involve striking the army and announcing a government recognised by the sponsoring countries**, along with some international institutions and organisations. It would deal a crushing blow to the Islamic and military currents in the country.

[Hemedti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamed_Hamdan_Dagalo) is the leader of the RSF.

So, is it true that the UAE is sponsoring the RSF coup in Sudan?

Comment: N.B. there [seems](https://en.qantara.de/content/sudans-coup-puppetmasters-the-uae-pulling-sudanese-strings) to be some evidence (in the form of aid) the UAE was happy with the previous (2019) regime change, which brought both the RSF and Burhan to their power-sharing arrangement. So that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: "Masonic"?!? If that is meant in any sort of traditional sense, that's a red flag immediately. "Freemasons"?

Comment: @paulgarrett: It seems to be used more like a slur in Sudan, along the lines of "Western Zionist Masonic American intelligence" based on a quick search. OTOH some in Africa seem to take those more literally at times https://www.economist.com/middle-east-and-africa/2018/02/22/a-fuss-over-freemasons-in-africa

Comment: Thanks, @Fizz, I had no idea...!

Comment: Even if a meeting of Hemedti with UAE President happened it would not be an evidence. The only evidence we can reliably evaluate is the classic *cui prodest?*. But as things stand I cannot see any advantage for any foreign power for the current turmoil.

Comment: "Masonic conspiracy" of "the Left and the Communists" of the Arab countries. I'd give more credit to Putin about Ukraine being governed by nazis who plotted to attack Russia under the NATO umbrella.